# Should I use null or empty string if the String is passed around in the code? (Java best practice)

Tags: java

I have a String which is optional in the API. If I don't get that parameter I am unsure if I should use an empty `String` or a `null` value. The value is being passed around in a lot of functions and being used in some of them.

I have been thinking about this and this is what I came up with.

- Using `null` could be better because it would throw NPE if a developer tries to use it without checking if it exists. `""` would not do that so the developer may think he is using the string when it does not exist.
- Using `""` could be better because if a developer wants to change something he/she won't need to check for null pointer. This could be beneficial when the developer does not need to know if the value exist like changing the encoding of the string.

What is the best practice in such a situation?

EDIT: I am looking for reasons why an approach is better than the other. And `Optional` sounds interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Empty string definitely is better than null. If you want to indicate that the setting is *optional*, and provide a different behavior, use `Optional<String>`.

Comment: I was looking for reasons on why is one better than the other. I am thinking that an empty string will not throw an error and it could hide problems in the code.

Comment: You already said it as much in the question: no NullPointerException, and if you want some treatment of not self providing a value, then `Optional` should be a better mechanism. There now is no longer a reason for risking an  NPE.

Comment: Isn't a NPE a good thing to let the developer know that the value is null? If there is no NPE could the code not be hiding problems?

Comment: The problem is, that the value may first be passed around, so there is no fail-fast, the bug becomes vague. The string "null" may appear. An Optional makes the usage explicit, preferably with an `param.ifPresent(value -> ...)`

Comment: My answer is "either a non-null String using a default" or an Optional." The decision for either one depends on the effort you want to impose, it must be worth it. A nullable object has no longer a justification to exist in _normal_ code.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, if `""` is not a valid value for that parameter, use `""`. Otherwise use `null`.

Regarding your first point, you'll get an `IndexOutOfRangeException` if you try to substring an empty string or call `charAt` or anything like that. So I don't think it's gonna encourage using it without checking for empty string. And there are lots of ways you get prevent an NPE.

An alternative is `Optional<String>`, but I think currently it's syntax looks too ugly. I would still use `""` if it is not considered a valid value.

Answer (score 0):

If you're returning a null String in your API, it is entirely possible that the developer consuming it will forget to check that its value is `null`. As Joop has already mentioned in his answer, use `Optional<String>`.

This forces the consumer of the API to check for its existence (or at the very least, think about how to handle its absence), e.g.

```
myAPI.ifPresent(/* do something with String */);
myAPI.map(String::toLowerCase).orElse("");
```